# Editing excel file using vbscript but the edits are taking too long to complete

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

/* The reason why I am using vb scrips to edit the excel file is: the excel file will be different all the time but the format will be the same and the user does not want to save VBA macro on their workbook.

I am getting values from Column 3 and adding those values to Column 9 at the end of it.

*/

```
Set xlApp=CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlBook=xlApp.Workbooks.Open("filepath", 0, true)
xlApp.visible=true


Set xlSheet=xlBook.Worksheets("Proposal Spreadsheet")
row=xlSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
col=xlSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

dim i 

For i=15 to xlSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count 
cell=xlSheet.Cells(i,3).Value
celli=xlSheet.Cells(i,9).Value+"("+cell+")" //I am combining column 3 with column 9

xlSheet.Cells(i,9).Value=celli


Next

xlBook.Save
xlApp.Run "Submit_To_iDesk"
xlBook.Close

xlApp.Quit
Set xlApp=Nothing 
Set xlBook=Nothing 
WScript.Quit
```

Comment: Your code is actually setting the value of column 9 to be the value that was in column 9 (`celli=xlSheet.Cells(i,9).Value` `xlSheet.Cells(i,9).Value=celli`) - which is possibly a bit pointless (unless you are replacing a formula with a value?).

Comment: You're very right! I could not find a way to add column3's values to column9's values without replacing it. Do you have any other suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Possibly use `xlSheet.Cells(i,9).Value=cell + celli` as the last line - so that it adds the two values.  But the next question is ... is it the setting of column 9's values that is taking the time, or is it the (unposted) `Submit_To_iDesk` macro that takes the time?

Comment: it is the setting of column 9's values is taking the time and won't give it a chance to run the macro.

Comment: It is overpassing the usedRange when passing the values in Col9. UsedRange is not working in this case

Comment: I have posted an answer, but I'm not very familiar with VBScript.  If it works I will leave it there.  If it doesn't then I will delete it again.

Comment: Did you want the values from column 3 to be enclosed by parentheses?

Comment: Also, does the workbook have much in the way of calculations?  If so, it may be better to switch `Calculation` to `xlCalculationManual` before updating the values.

Comment: @ThomasInzina OHHH!  Is that what is meant - I had just thought it was meant to be addition.  (I saw the question before the last edit.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `UsedRange` is not returning a useful number, use one of the more reliable ways of finding the last used cell in a column:

```
Set xlApp=CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlBook=xlApp.Workbooks.Open("filepath", 0, true)
xlApp.visible=true

Set xlSheet=xlBook.Worksheets("Proposal Spreadsheet")
row=xlSheet.Cells(xlSheet.Rows.Count, 9).End(-4162).Row ' -4162 is equivalent of "xlUp"

dim i 

For i=15 to row
    cell=xlSheet.Cells(i,3).Value
    celli=xlSheet.Cells(i,9).Value

    xlSheet.Cells(i,9).Value=celli & "(" & cell & ")"
Next

xlBook.Save
xlApp.Run "Submit_To_iDesk"
xlBook.Close

xlApp.Quit
Set xlApp=Nothing 
Set xlBook=Nothing 
WScript.Quit
```

Comment: It worked out for me! I later on found out that it was actually my laptop that is processing the macro longer. I tested it on other laptops and it works under 30 seconds. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: row=xlSheet.Cells(xlSheet.Rows.Count, 9).End(-4162).Row . This part works awesome! Again, million thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The key to speeding up your procedure is reducing the number of write operations.
Here is how I would do it

- Set a range variable (**target**) to the target cells in column 9
- Create an array of **values** from the target range
- Edit the elements of the values array Write the values array back over the original
- target range in 1 operation

---

```
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\best buy\Desktop\Book1.xlsx", 0, True)

xlApp.Visible = True
xlApp.ScreenUpdating = False
Set xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets("Proposal Spreadsheet")

Dim i, values, LastRow, target

With xlSheet
    LastRow = xlSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Set target = .Range(.Cells(15, 9), .Cells(LastRow, 9))
    values = target.Value

    For i = LBound(values, 1) To UBound(values, 1)
        values(i, 1) = values(i, 1) & "(" & .Cells(i + 15 - LBound(values, 1), 3) & ")"
    Next
    target.Value = values
End With

xlBook.Save
'xlApp.Run "Submit_To_iDesk"
xlBook.Close
xlApp.ScreenUpdating = True
xlApp.Quit
Set xlApp = Nothing
Set xlBook = Nothing
WScript.Quit
```

Comment: I like your clean code. I will test it out but for now it looks some syntax of it do not match with of VBscript but thank you so much!

Comment: I haven't tested it but I am confident that the syntax is correct

Comment: Somehow, the code is keep getting error on this line >>  Set target = .Range(.Cells(15, 9), .Cells(15, LastRow)). Perhaps, the range is not defined correctly. I'd really appreciate if you could update me on this. Thanks

Comment: @GereltuyaBatdemberel refactored my code and tested it.  Let me know how it performs.

Comment: @YowE3K Thanks again.  I should have use a better dataset when I tested my code.

Comment: I forgot to tag you! so wanted to say thanks! It worked out great!

Comment: I'm happy to hear that.  :)